# How many people spoke to Apollo 8 from outside the US?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, apollo-8, honeysuckle-creek, australia

@PearsonArtPhoto's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33456/12102) links to the page [Apollo 8, 21 – 28 December 1968](https://www.honeysucklecreek.net/msfn_missions/Apollo_8_mission/hl_apollo8.html) by Hamish Lindsay at [honeysucklecreek.net](https://www.honeysucklecreek.net/).

It shows a clipping from *The Canberra Times* front page, "With thanks to Mike Dinn. Scan: Colin Mackellar."

**Question:** Several people spoke to the Apollo 8 astronauts from NASA ground control. But how many people spoke to them from outside the US?

---

> Australia’s Voice, English Accent
>
> Mr. M. J. Dinn, a 35-year-old Englishman, became yesterday afternoon the first man working at an Australian space station to speak to the crew of Apollo-8.
>
> On an instruction from Flight Command, Houston, Mr. Dinn, who is the assistant director at Honeysuckle Creek, told the astronauts that a “minor fault” had developed in a voice-controlled relay at the station.
>
> This meant, Mr. Dinn said last night, that if the crew had wanted to talk to Houston the ground-station would not have been able to transmit an immediate reply. His job was to tell them of this situation.
>
> The fault was eradicated by switching to another relay.
>
> About 40 technicians at the Honeysuckle Creek-Tidbinbilla complex began tracking the flight about 10:30am yesterday.
>
> They worked for 12 hours, with the Carnarvon, WA, station in support at various times.

[image]

> The Canberra Times’ front page also reported Mike Dinn’s brief conversation with the Apollo 8 astronauts when there was a comms problem between Houston and Honeysuckle.
>
> Doubtless Bernard Scrivener, the station’s admin and public relations officer – or [Don Witten](https://www.honeysucklecreek.net/msfn_missions/Apollo_8_mission/apollo8_GoddardNx.html), visiting PAO from Goddard – would have alerted the newspaper to this local story.
>
> The exchange starts at 3:15 [on this (750kb mp3) excerpt](https://www.honeysucklecreek.net/audio/A8_audio/A8_HSK/A8_Tape2_Tr2_commbreak.mp3).
>
> Only Houston and the downlink are heard on this recording made at Honeysuckle, Sadly, Mike’s uplink was not.
>
> Scan and notes: Colin Mackellar.

[image]

> John Saxon (background) and Mike Dinn at the Ops Console, December 1968 ([from the calendar](https://www.honeysucklecreek.net/images/images_Apollo_8/Dinn_and_Grant_Dec_1968.jpg)), and almost certainly during Apollo 8. Photo: Ron Hicks.

Comment: This might be of interest: [*Carnarvon and Apollo: One Giant Leap for a Small Australian Town*](https://www.amazon.com/Carnarvon-Apollo-Giant-Small-Australian/dp/1877058971)

Comment: This may be answerable by 270 pages of transcript trawling: https://historycollection.jsc.nasa.gov/JSCHistoryPortal/history/mission_trans/AS08_CM.PDF

Comment: @Hohmannfan bounty expires in 22 hours (plus 24 hour "grace period") just fyi.

Comment: @Fred ditto....

Comment: The flat earth society getting a mention in the news briefs :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb5gd.png

Comment: @Hohmannfan rotf-ing and lol-ing, thanks!

Comment: It not about Apollo 8, but you might find this video interesting: [*How Australia Helped Save Apollo 13*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ovmUiwlPWI)

Comment: @Fred cool! I've just asked [Help understanding how these components of a Honeysuckle Creek dish antenna work](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40928/12102)

Comment: @uhoh: You're very observant! I hadn't noticed the two devices on the side of the dish.

Comment: Just in case you hadn't seen this before: [*Carnarvon Tracking Station*](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2019-07-14/the-vital-role-played-by-carnarvon-in-the-apollo-11-moon-landing/11261800)

Comment: @Fred [How does this large, flat antenna made from overlapping signals at Australia's Carnarvon Space Tracking Center work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40945/12102)

Comment: Not Apollo 8, but John Glenn & Friendship 7. NASA established a tracking station at [Muchea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muchea_Tracking_Station), Western Australia, which became operational in 1960. The station is now defunct. "Muchea Communications Technician Gerry O'Connor became the [first Australian to speak with an astronaut](http://www.cdscc.nasa.gov/Pages/history.html) on 20 February 1962, when he contacted John Glenn aboard Friendship 7 on his first pass over the West Australian coast."

Comment: @Fred it seems that I've just asked [First radio contact between an Australian ground station and a spacecraft? First voice communications?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43475/12102)

Comment: @Fred that link isn't working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least not any others in the onboard and air-to-ground transcripts, as far as I can see

https://historycollection.jsc.nasa.gov/JSCHistoryPortal/history/mission_trans/AS08_TEC.PDF
https://historycollection.jsc.nasa.gov/JSCHistoryPortal/history/mission_trans/AS08_CM.PDF

Honeysuckle communications have been preserved and digitized, available for download here, with chunks ordered by mission highlights.

https://honeysucklecreek.net/msfn_missions/Apollo_8_mission/apollo8_audio.html

The episode is recorded there, but only the downlink portion.

*As far as I can tell*, there's no other communication by people outside Houston CC. But I'm not very familiar with the routines of the Apollo communication procedures, so I can not completely exclude the possibility of some additional comm techs speaking from Honeysuckle and Madrid.